Como sacar un subtotal de filas y dividirlo por el total en SQL server
Buen dia, estoy iniciando en SQL server y tengo el siguiente problema, dada la tabla:
CREATE TABLE prod.FactInvoice(
    [Id Factura] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Fecha de Venta] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Id Vendedor] INT,
    [Id Cliente] INT,
    [Id Region] INT
    );


Necesito sacar la cantidad de facturas realizadas por cada vendedor y dividirlo por la cantidad total de facturas (osea el total de filas de la columna [Id Factura]), puedo sacar el total x vendedor asi:
SELECT DISTINCT [Id Vendedor],
    COUNT([Id Factura]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Id Vendedor]) AS [Ventas x Vendedor]
FROM prod.FactInvoice
ORDER BY [Id Vendedor];


Pero no encuentro la forma de en la misma consulta sacar la cantidad total de facturas para poder hacer la division.
Tambien tengo las siguientes tablas que tienen relacion con la de facturas como para aplicar un join en la consulta:
CREATE TABLE prod.FactTransacciones(
    [Id Transaccion] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Fecha de Recepcion] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Id Factura] INT,
    [Id Producto] INT,
    Cantidad INT,
    [Precio Unitario] DECIMAL(9, 2),
    [Costo Unitario] DECIMAL(9, 2)
    );

CREATE TABLE prod.DimVendedores(
    [Id Vendedor] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha de Nacimiento] DATE NOT NULL,
    Mercado INT
    );

Pero sigo teniendo problemas para sacar el total de filas dentro de la misma consulta.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Usa la clausula OVER para sacar el total por grupo....

Podrías sacar el total contando las facturas de la tabla y luego simplemente dividir.
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Id Vendedor],
    COUNT([Id Factura]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Id Vendedor]) AS [Ventas x Vendedor],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prod.FactInvoice) AS [TotalFacturas] -- No es necesario que sea una columna pero para que veas la división
    CAST(COUNT([Id Factura]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Id Vendedor]) AS float) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prod.FactInvoice) AS FLOAT) 
FROM 
    prod.FactInvoice
ORDER BY 
    [Id Vendedor];

Esta respuesta es más elegante, usa OVER y más fácil de comprender.

Justo lo que estaba necesitando, muchas gracias

Una forma práctica es manejar el total en una variable:
DECLARE @Total  BIGINT
SELECT  @Total = COUNT(1)
    FROM prod.FactInvoice

Para luego aplicarlo en el calculo:
SELECT  [Id Vendedor],
    COUNT(1)                    AS [Ventas x Vendedor],
    @Total                      AS [Ventas Totales],
    COUNT(1) / (@Total * 1.0)   AS [Porcentaje]
    FROM prod.FactInvoice
    GROUP BY [Id Vendedor]
    ORDER BY [Id Vendedor];


Lo habia hecho asi pero me habia olvidado de comentar que necesitan que cree un VIEW y no puedo usar variables por ese motivo.

Siguiendo la línea de la consulta que ya tienes, puedes obtener la cuenta de todas las ventas dejando en blanco la cláusula over:
over ()

Integrado a tu consulta, podría ser algo como:
select distinct
         [Id Vendedor]
       , COUNT([Id Factura]) over (partition by [Id Vendedor]) [Ventas x Vendedor]
       , COUNT([Id Factura]) over () [Ventas Totales]
       , COUNT([Id Factura]) over (partition by [Id Vendedor]) * 100.0 / COUNT([Id Factura]) over () [PorcentajeVentas]
  from FactInvoice

En una prueba rápida, obtengo resultados como estos:
Id Vendedor Ventas x Vendedor Ventas Totales PorcentajeVentas
----------- ----------------- -------------- ---------------------------------------
121         7                 30             23.333333333333
127         12                30             40.000000000000
129         1                 30             3.333333333333
131         10                30             33.333333333333

(4 rows affected)


Intenta cambiando un poquito el enfoque, si quieres buscar ventas por vendedor, el punto de partida deben ser los vendedores.
despues intenta un query como el siguiente:
SELECT t1.[Id Vendedor], t2.VentasXVendedor, t3.VentasTotales, (t2.VentasXVendedor / t3.VentasTotales) As [Porcentaje]
from prod.DimVendedores t1
OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT COUNT(*) As [VentasXVendedor]
          FROM prod.FactInvoice x1
         where x1.[Id Vendedor] = t1.[Id Vendedor]) t2
OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT COUNT(*) As [VentasTotales]
          FROM prod.FactInvoice x1) t3
where t2.VentasXVendedor > 0

lo que hace es, buscar todos los vendedores, luego buscas sus ventas, sacas el total y al final con el where descartamos los vendedores que no tuvieron ventas.
